# How to programmatically retrieve polygon bounding area?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

The geocoding (or reverse geocoding) results typically have bounding boxes for each address_component, but these are very gross boxes.

Yet, google seems to have good complex polygons for lots of regions. See this google maps query for "WC1N" :

["new" Google Maps query for WC1N](http://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=WC1N&data=!1m4!1m3!1d5818!2d-0.1217637!3d51.5235452!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x48761b305e78de37:0x96d6d7a74e712fbf!3m8!1m3!1d5818!2d-0.1206479!3d51.5230246!3m2!1i1189!2i900!4f13.1!4m2!3d51.524144!4d-0.1218934)

Notice there is a very nice red dotted line that outlines the post code. This exists for other areas as well. For example a query for "Berkeley, CA, USA" has a very complex red dotted line.

So, how do you get these polygons programmatically? a geocode query itself doesn't seem to do it. The response to this query for WC1N just has the boxes:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=WC1N&sensor=true

As does a query giving a lat/lng that inside either the bounding box or polygon.

Is this data available someplace else? Or are there plans to make it available via the google API?

Comment: I'm also in need of the neighborhood polygon data. It looks like Google has the best data available compared to Maponics and (the opensource) quattroshapes from Foursquare. The only clue I could find about this lies buried in this issue https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109. It's really a shame they didn't really provide *any* real feedback or took action in 7 years! Hopefully someone else sees this post and knows more than us, or maybe knows someone at Google, if so, please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out almost everyone treats this data as propritary. There isn't a way to get it from google or the like.

However, there are shapefiles you can download that have a lot of the data. post codes, zip codes, counties, etc. But then you have to deal with the complexity of shapefiles.

mapbox & OpenStreetMap have some polygon lookup facilities as well.